# Trying to delete multiple appfabric cache names using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, powershell, caching

My goal is to write a batch script that will delete all of the cache names from a particular cache server.

The code I wrote below errors because it cannot execute the AppFabric PowerShell commands. It returns `"Remove-Cache -CacheName blahblah" is not a recognized as an internal or external command`.

I guess what I need to figure out and I need help from you guys is how can I use the shell script `FOR /F` command but yet be able to execute AppFabric PowerShell commands.

I tried adding the line:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration;Use-CacheCluster"
```

in the beginning of the batch script to first bring up the PowerShell window, import the AppFabric module and then run the batch script. But because PowerShell doesn't recognize `FOR /F`, it bombs there.  I'm trying to delete multiple cachenames, but I'm just too not advanced enough to do it. HELP!

```
:
@echo off

REM using PING and batch line retrieval... only IP address info is called out from ping request
FOR /F "tokens=2,3" %%A IN ('ping %computername% -n 1 -4') DO IF "from"== "%%A" set "IP=%%~B"
echo %IP:~0,-1%

REM GET-CacheClusterHealth > C:\output.txt
REM FIND /n /i "NamedCache" C:\output.txt > C:\results.txt


FOR /F "tokens=4" %%i in (C:\results.txt) DO "Remove-Cache -CacheName %%i"

DEL "C:\output.txt"
DEL "C:\results.txt"

ECHO ALL Cache names have been deleted from Cache Server %IP:~0,-1%
Pause
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just do it in PowerShell other than knowing batch scripting better than powershell? If you are against going straight PS, then it sounds like you need to write a powershell script, then call that script rather than just trying to run commands directly like you are.

Comment: If I had the knowhow on writing it in powershell I would :-), I dont know the equivalent of the FOR /F using tokens in powershell code. I tried calling this batch from a .PS1 file and I still got the same not recognized commands error.

Comment: Sorry about the REM command statements, I was debugging along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest it looks like you are making this way more complicated than it needs to be. PowerShell is the way things are moving so you may want to look into how it works a bit more. What you probably need is something along the lines of (kind of pseudo-code since I don't have the actual cmdlet to reference):

```
Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration
Use-CacheCluster
$ServerName = "SomeServer01"
$ServerPort = "22233"
Get-Cache -HostName $ServerName -CachePort $ServerPort | ForEach{Remove-Cache $_.CacheName}
```

Now I don't know what is returned from `Get-Cache` but I imagine that it returns an array of things and from looking at your script one of the properties is NamedCache, which is what you want to work with. The above example would import the module needed to perform the commands. Then it sets the cache cluster to the current host, assign a variable to the name of a server that you want to work with, and then another variable to the port for it. Lastly it performs the Get-Cache command against the specified host and port, and sends the results of that to a ForEach loop that performs the Remove-Cache command against all of the items returned's NamedCache property. As I said before I assume it returns an array of objects which contain a NamedCache property.

As for `FOR /F` in PowerShell, what you could do if you really want to go that route is something like:

```
Get-Content Results.txt | ForEach{Remove-Cache -CacheName $_.Split(" ")[3]}
```

That gets the contents of the file, and then for each line it splits that line at each space, and references the 4th item (PowerShell's Split method will turn the string into an array of strings, and since arrays start at record 0 in PowerShell `[3]` references the 4th string in the array).

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try your solution out and report back! :-)

Comment: Changed NamedCache to CacheName and the parameter -Port to -CachePort in your code and it worked flawlessly.  Thank you for your help and I'll be educating myself on powershell!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If this took care of your question please mark the answer as accepted so future searchers can find it easily.